# NullPointerException: createProgressDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, progressdialog

Get next error from Crashlytics for `Android version: 10`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:196)
       at android.app.ColorBaseAlertDialog.<init>(ColorBaseAlertDialog.java:33)
       at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:208)
       at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:204)
       at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:112)
       at com.sau.authenticator.widget.fragment.BaseFragment.createProgressDialog(BaseFragment.java:46)
       at com.sau.authenticator.widget.fragment.BaseFragment.showLoadProgress(BaseFragment.java:41)
       at com.sau.authenticator.widget.fragment.WebViewFragment$webViewClient$1.onPageStarted(WebViewFragment.java:69)
       at i6.c(i6.java:2)
       at Hn.handleMessage(Hn.java:145)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

In my function `createProgressDialog`, which is called in BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    private var progressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    val activityComponents: ActivityComponentsContract?
        get() = activity?.activityComponentsContract

    override fun onDestroy() {
        progressDialog?.dismiss()
        progressDialog = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    protected fun showLoadProgress() {
        if (progressDialog == null) progressDialog = createProgressDialog()
        progressDialog?.show()
    }

    private fun createProgressDialog(): ProgressDialog? {
        val dialog = ProgressDialog(activity, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large)
        return dialog
    }

    protected fun dismissLoadProgress() {
        progressDialog?.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Here is code of my WebViewFragment:

```
class WebViewFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private var url = ""
    private var title = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            url = it.getString(KEY_URL, "")
            title = it.getString(KEY_TITLE, "")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        activityComponents?.updateAppbar(
            title = title,
            backActionImageResId = R.drawable.ic_appbar_action_back
        )
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        customWebView?.webViewClient = webViewClient
        customWebView?.loadUrl(url)
    }

    private val webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            showLoadProgress()
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            dismissLoadProgress()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val KEY_URL = "KEY_URL"

        fun newBundle(url: String = "", title: String): Bundle {
            return Bundle().apply {
                putString(KEY_URL, url)
                putString(KEY_TITLE, title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `WebView`, but it seems like by the time `onPageStarted()` is called your user already navigated away (or rotated his device). Hence your `Fragment`'s `onDestroyView()` is likely called already, but you are not notifying your `WebView` that starts loading your url. That's why `activity` is `null` and you get the exception.

So on your `WebViewFragment`'s lifecycle callbacks make sure you notify your `WebView` too:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    customWebView?.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    customWebView?.onPause()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    customWebView?.stopLoading() // this should prevent onPageStarted() from being called
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what I should change in my fragment with WebView. I added the fragment code to the question.

Comment: I updated the answer with code examples. The call to `stopLoading()` should prevent that `onPageStarted()` is called and thus that the exception is thrown.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `customWebView` in `onViewCreated()`, I didn't see that in your code

Comment: Thx for the answer, but how do you see initialization? Right now i have there `        customWebView?.webViewClient = webViewClient
        customWebView?.loadUrl(url)`

Comment: Well, I expected to see `customWebView = ...` there. I can't find where you declare `customWebView` either.

Comment: i have `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_web_view.*`

Comment: Ah and I didn't see the imports. Nevermind the initialization comment!

Comment: also in my BaseFragment i modified `val dialog = ProgressDialog(activity ?: return null, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error happened when your Fragment was DestroyView. I am not entirely sure about this. You can reproduce by load a large web page, then navigate to another fragment so that WebViewFragment / onViewDestroyed is executed. Print logs in onPageStarted and onPageFinished. If you see them being called when you destroy the view, this is exactly the cause. At this point you just need to check the lifecycle state to show or hide progress.